# Entering a Catholic or Protestant church

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, christianity, contemporary-halacha

According to Jewish Law, is one allowed to enter a Catholic or Protestant church?

Comment: L'mai nafka minah between a Catholic and Protestant church?